# What does “акция” mean in this sentence?

Tags: значения

I am aware of two meanings of the word “акция”. It may mean

1. a stock (a financial instrument), or
2. a political, diplomatic or military act.

When I was in Moscow a few months ago, I saw ads that read *“У нас акция”*, meaning “We have a sale”.

What does the word “акция” mean in this sentence? Is it a new meaning? Does the word “акция” have any other meanings?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The meaning here is close to second statement proposed: "a political, diplomatic or military act", because it is an "**action of sale**", which sounds silly in English.

*"Акция"* is an abridged version of *"рекламная акция"*, а popular term emerged in the 90s in post-soviet territory. *"Рекламная акция"* could, but shouldn't be translated as "**an action of advertisement**", because it sounds silly in English too. What it really means is "**an action of product or service promotion**". And product promotion in Russia is a sale in 90% of cases.

There is no other meaning of *"акция"* I can think of, so if you see a word *"акция"* again in unknown context, I suggest that it is more likely an act of something, and not a stock.

Comment: This sense of "акция" is also probably affected by the German cognate Aktion, which is the normal word for "sale".

Answer (score 4):

> Is it a new meaning?

Yes this is new meaning. Before 90s, the word for "sale" was "Распродажа".

I guess Распродажа sounds now obsolete, hardly used.

Акция в смысле Распродажа/sale probably did not yet make it into the dictionaries.

Comment: I certainly wouldn't call the word распродажа obsolete. It is used all over the place, both online and in Moscow.

Answer (score 2):

АКЦИЯ, -и; ж. [от лат. aсtio - действие]. Офиц.
Действие, выступление кого-л., предпринимаемое для достижения какой-л. цели; акт (1 зн.). Дипломатическая а. Политическая, террористическая а. А. милосердия. Кем-л. принята, совершена новая а. Осуществить задуманную акцию.

http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%E0%EA%F6%E8%FF

В данном случае "акция" есть действия, направленные на привлечение внимания к конкретному бренду. Например, продажа по заниженной цене. Это рекламная акция.

Применительно к Москве "акция", как правило, идет постоянно, никаких реально занижаемых цен при [рекламной] акции не бывает.

Comment: Hello Abilis. Since the question is in English, do you mind adding an English version to your answer? Thank you.

Comment: My English bad, therefore  there is one of the way to practise Russian. :-)

Nevertheless, 'акция' - Action Advertising - the actions directed on drawing attention to any brand. For example: reduction of price.

Comment: Ok, don't worry, we'll wait for someone to edit your answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

*Акция* is a promotional event in this case. For example, *акция* may be a discount, a gift or two-for-one thing.

> Скидка 50% на холодильник до 15 декабря
>
> При покупке шубы - брюки в подарок
>
> 2 шарфа по цене одного

Answer (score -3):

Акция - is an Angicism that is being misused everywhere. While Russian language has it's own words, stupid people keep using foreign substitutes.
In your question's case, it means 'sale' - 'раcпродажа', or 'discount' - 'скидка'.